# vue img assets url

Tags: vue.js, assets

Доброго времени суток.

Есть компонент на vue.js который в дате хранит массив объектов с описанием ссылок. Изображения хранятся так /src/assets/img/.В шаблоне черз v-for пробегаю через этот массив и в атрибут src тэга img пытаюсь вставить ссылку на картинку (ссылка вида `"@/assets/img/pic.jpg"`) в результате vue ссылку не обрабатывает и втсавляет как есть (`<img src="@/assets/img/service_delivery.jpg" alt="Доставка">`). Не могу понять, что мне нужно сделать что бы в атрибуте ссылка на картинку сформировалась правильно.

```js
<template>
  <div>
      <table class="services-table">
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(serv, i) in services" v-bind:key="i">
            <td><img v-bind:src="serv.icon" v-bind:alt="serv.name"></td>
            <td>{{ serv.name }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'ervices',
  data: function() {
    return {
      services: [
        { name: 'Такси', icon: "@/assets/img/service_taxi.jpg", },
        { name: 'Доставка', icon: "@/assets/img/service_delivery.jpg", }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать require или import, чтобы сообщить webpack, что этот путь должен рассматриваться как модуль:

```
<img :src="require(serv.icon)" alt="">
```

[Подобный ишус на гите](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/126)

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за помощь.

Не сработал у меня вариант через require хоть убей пишет в консоль, что модуль не наеден. Видимо руки ну очень кривые.
Нашёл на EN версии топик с решением где человек прям на 90% мою проблему описал, может кому поможет: [Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082968/vue-js-2-vue-cannot-find-files-from-assets-folder-v-for). Следуя этим инструкциям я, к сожалению, так же получил в консоль сообщение о не возможности найти модуль.

Мое решение проблемы оказалось таким. Нашёл в офф документации вариант через public [Ссылка](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder) + использовал абсолютный путь до картинок - так работает.

Answer (score 0):

если еще актуально как вариант

```js
 { name: 'Такси', icon: require("@/assets/img/service_taxi.jpg"), },
```

вот такой вариант должен заработать, аналогичная ситуация была у меня

Answer (score 0):

img :src="require(`../assets/images/` + product_data.image)"
плюс в твоем объекте:
product_data: [ { image: photo.jpg } ] - здесь просто наименование картинки и формат

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]